# exercising the abdominals, height

Tags: abdominals

Recently, my friend said that *doing sit ups* will **prevent growth height**. Is that true or just a whispers?

Comment: Please take the tour of this site, see http://fitness.stackexchange.com/tour Right now the question is a bit out of scope.

Comment: I'm inclined to think your friend is just lazy :P.

Comment: so it means he is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other reasons you should probably avoid sit ups, but your friend has no idea what he's talking about.